# How to use SERIAL BAUD rate 115200 instead of 9600 to start telnet using python script

Tags: python, telnet

I have a script `rfcserver.py`. I am using for telnet session for gateway.
Till now I am using 9600 baudrate default but now i have to use 115200 baud rate. How to do that?

Comment: A telnet session (TCP) does not have a baud rate like a serial connection.

Comment: Are you using any python serial library like pyserial or any for interfacing with serial devices?

Comment: I am using rfc2217.py.